# How can I find decompositions in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

### Decompositions in $\mathbb{Z}$

In $\mathbb{Z}$ you can find a decomposition of any element $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ by factorization such that

$$n = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{v_p(n)}$$

So for a concrete example:

$$48 = 2 \cdot 24 = 2^2 \cdot 12 = 2^3 \cdot 6 = 2^4 \cdot 3$$

### Decompsitions in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$

Now let $R := (\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}], +, \cdot)$ be a ring with $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] := \{a + b \cdot \sqrt{d} | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

You can composite more elements in this ring, e.g. for $d = -1$

$$-i \cdot (1+i)^2 = -i (1 + 2i - 1) = -i(2i) = 2$$

So obviously at least one prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a decomposition in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

### Questions

Is there any algorithm with which I can find such a decomposition of any prime $p$ and for any $d$? Are there decompositions of numbers $a+b\sqrt{d}$ with $a \neq 0 \neq b$ (and of course $d \neq 0$)?
Can you please describe it generally and with $17$?

If $b = 0$ I can factorize $a$ as I know it in $\mathbb{Z}$, but as soon as I only have prime numbers left, I might still be able to further factorize the number.

Is the decomposition in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ unique? According to fundamental theorem of arithmetic it is unique in $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know if it is still true for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Uniqueness of the factorization in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$**

The best we can expect is that a factorization into irreducibles is unique up to permuting the factors and multiplying factors with units. Rings in which every element has an unique (in this sense) factorization are called [unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) (UFD). For example, the ring of the Gaussian integers ($d=-1$) is an UFD. But not all rings $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ are UFDs, a counterexample is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, in which $4 = 2\cdot 2 = (1 + \sqrt{-3})(1 - \sqrt{-3})$ has two factorizations.

**Computation of the factorization in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$**

An important tool for such rings is the norm function
$$N : R \to \mathbb{N}, \quad a + b\sqrt{d}\mapsto \lvert{(a + b\sqrt{d})(a - b\sqrt{d})\rvert}.$$
Its crucial property is that it is multiplicative ($N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$). We get the following consequences:

- $x\in R^\times \iff N(x) = 1$
- $N(x)$ prime in $\mathbb{Z} \implies x$ irreducible in $R$
- Each proper factorization of $x\in R$ implies a proper factorization of $N(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

As a result, we get the following method to factor $x$ in $R$: First compute $N(x)$. For each factor $a$ of $N(x)$ (in $\mathbb Z$), enumerate all elements of $R$ with norm $a$ (up to multiplication with units, there are only finitely many), and test if $x$ is divisible by $a$. Then continue with the two factors you found.

This is the basic idea of factorization in $R$. The method can be refined by special knowledge about the ring $R$ (depending on $d$).

**Example: Factorization of $x = 17$ in the ring of Gaussian numbers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$**

Here $N(x) = \lvert x\rvert^2$ and $N(17) = 17^2$.
Assume $17 = rs$ with $r,s\in R\setminus R^\times$.
Application of $N$ yields $N(17) = N(rs)$, so $17^2 = N(r)N(s)$ and hence $N(r) = N(s) = 17$.

To find the elements of norm $17$, we look at the norm equation $N(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2 = 17$.
The 8 solutions are $(a,b)\in\{(\pm 1, \pm 4), (\pm 4, \pm 1)\}$.
So up to multiplication with units (the units in $R$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$), the elements of norm $17$ are $1 + 4i$ and $1 - 4i$.
This leads to the factorization
$$
17 = (1 + 4i)(1 - 4i).
$$

Comment: @azimut: Is the following correct: $a$ is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow N(a)$ is prime

Comment: Just a comment: you have implicitly used the fact $N(a)=\pm 1$ if and only if $a$ is a unit. If you dont use this fact, you could happen to "delete" some factor of $a$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: Thanks. I've moved the $N(x) = 1 \iff x\in R^\times$ argument from the application part to the general part.

Comment: @moose: No, it isn't. By the multiplicativity of $N$ you get $N(a)$ prime $\implies a$ irreducible. But for example in the Gaussian numbers, there are no elements of norm $3$. Hence, the element $3$ is irreducible, but its norm $9$ is not a prime number in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @rschwieb: done. And thanks for the feedback!